# warning MSB8004: Output Directory does not end with a trailing slash.

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I am getting a warning in my VC++ project as

> 1>...Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(368,5):
>   warning MSB8004: Output Directory does not end with a trailing slash. 
>   This build instance will add the slash as it is required to allow
>   proper evaluation of the Output Directory.

I do have OutputDirectory value correctly set with trailing slash in my configuration property. How do I debug the path which is creating the problem ?

Comment: Do you have set Intermediate Directory value with trailing slash in your configuration property?

Answer (score 7):

That warning only occurs when $(OutDir) has no trailing slash, see Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets line 29. So even though you say you set it correctly (Output Directory in the properties sets $(OutDir) in the project file), msbuild doesn't see that. My guess: you set Output Directory for e.g. the Debug|Win32 configuration but are now building Release|Win32 or so. Or, it gets overridden somewhere else in your project file: open it with a text editor and look for OutDir.